# Replace values in pandas columns based on starting value of column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
  Index1 Index2  -2  -1   0   1   2  -1 ph  -2 ph  1 ph  2 ph
0      A      W   0   0  28  29  18    -28    -28     1   -10
1      B      X   0  20  26  21  27     -6    -26    -5     1
2      C      Y  19  20  20  17  17      0     -1    -3    -3
3      D      Z  15   0  15  18  18    -15      0     3     3
```

The columns satrting with '-' can have 0 values. And I want to replace them using a dash like follows.

```
  Index1 Index2  -2  -1   0   1   2 -1 ph -2 ph  1 ph  2 ph
0      A      W   -   -  28  29  18   -28   -28     1   -10
1      B      X   -  20  26  21  27    -6   -26    -5     1
2      C      Y  19  20  20  17  17     -    -1    -3    -3
3      D      Z  15   -  15  18  18   -15     -     3     3
```

I have currently done this for each column manually:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create DataFrame
data = {'Index1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        'Index2': ['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'],
        '-2': [0, 0, 19, 15],
        '-1': [0, 20, 20, 0],
        '0': [28, 26, 20, 15],
        '1': [29, 21, 17, 18],
        '2': [18, 27, 17, 18]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.assign(**df[['-1','-2','1', '2']].sub(df['0'], axis=0).add_suffix(' ph'))


df['-1'].replace(to_replace=0, value='-', inplace=True)
df['-2'].replace(to_replace=0, value='-', inplace=True)
df['-1 ph'].replace(to_replace=0, value='-', inplace=True)
df['-2 ph'].replace(to_replace=0, value='-', inplace=True)
```

However, the columns (except for the indexes) can vary (so could be -3,-2,1,0,1 etc.) So I want to update my code to say: if the column name starts with a '-' replace 0s using a '-'

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with `regex` for get columns names starting by `-`, replace and pass to [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.DataFrame.html):

```
df.update(df.filter(regex='^-').replace(to_replace=0, value='-'))
```

Or is possible create boolean DataFrame by [`str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) and [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) with  replace by [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df.update(df.mask(df.eq(0) & df.columns.str.startswith('-'), '-'))
```

Another approach is create mask:

```
m = df.columns.str.startswith('-') 
df.loc[:, m] = df.loc[:, m].replace(to_replace=0, value='-')
```